# How to split the string before the 3rd occurrence of a "/" in Java

Tags: java, split

I have:

```
/xxx/yyy/aaa/bbb/abc.xml (or)
/xxx/yyy/aaa/abc.xml (or)
/xxx/yyy/aaa/bbb/ccc/abc.xml
```

But I need only:

```
/xxx/yyyy
```

How do I implement this in Java?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks in advance won't work; show us what you have tried and what failed. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! Please visit [help]

Comment: See [`String.substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) and [`String.indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)). With those twos, you can do it simply, so simply that I will let you do it.

Comment: Try `str.replaceAll("((/[^/]*){2}).*", "$1")`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#ordinalIndexOf(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)) class for this.

Sample code snippet for your question,

```
    String str = "/xxx/yyy/aaa/bbb/abc.xml";

    int index = StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(str , "/" , 3);

    String result = str.substring(0,index);
```

Or you can use indexOf method iteratively,

```
    String str = "/xxx/yyy/aaa/bbb/abc.xml";

    int index = 0 , count = 1;

    while(count != 3)
    {
         index = str.indexOf("/" , index+1);
         count++;
    }

    String result = str.substring(0,index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.split("/") for splitting and concat first 2 elements:

```
for(String string: input){
  String[] splitedStrings = string.split("/");
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("/");
  for(int i = 1; i < 3 && i < splitedStrings.length; i++){
    result.append(splitedStrings[i]).append("/");
  }
  System.out.println("Result: " + result.toString());
}
```

https://pastebin.com/kpg5VtMk

Answer (score 0):

```
FilenameUtils.getFullPathNoEndSeparator(str).replaceAll("((/[^/]*){2}).*", "$1")
```

I used this its working fine for me.